# I have way too many triangles on my mesh

Tags: mesh, faces, subdivision-surface, remesh

I have way too many triangles on my mesh, I used *Decimate* to reduce the number of faces while keeping the shape smooth, but I destroyed everything.

I saw that we could reduce the number of face, with bare hands, but I don't understand how to do it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this right, you would like to try and reduce the vertices on the top
bit, so they match better with the lower bit that has much fewer vertices.

When selecting a few of the vertices on the top, you can press "M" to get to the Merge menu. From there you can select what ever suits you (depends on your selection order as well sometimes.)

(btw, I have used Shift+R to repeat last action if I wanted to bypass the merge menu.)

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Or maybe select the top face and then M, B, F9 and adjust the distance.